# How do I use the /tellraw command in minecraft 1.10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a map but the `/tellraw` command won't work in Minecraft 1.10, not 1.9 or 1.8 just 1.10 it used to work perfectly in 1.8 as:

```
/tellraw @p {text:"what ever you want",color:red,bold:true,underlined:true,clickEvent:{action:open_url,value:"a url"}}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What was the last version it worked on + what is the complete command?

Comment: it work on 1.8 and the command is /tellraw @p {text:"what ever you want",color:red,bold:true,underlined:true,clickEvent:{action:open_url,value:"a url"}}

Comment: no that not it but thanks

Comment: Actually that is the answer.

Comment: i Tried that but it did not work

Answer (score 2):

Starting with 1.9, the parts of the game that you use JSON (`/tellraw`, `/title`, and signs) needs to be actually JSON compliant, so you need to use quotation marks on actions too. This should work:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"my text","color":"red","bold":true,"underlined":true,"clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"url"}}]
```

You can generate JSON like this at https://www.minecraftjson.com

Comment: I believe tellraw is the only affected command

Comment: sorry that did not work but thanks

Comment: but i think it dos need a JSON compliant like you said

Comment: @Unionhawk `/title` and sign text also requires strict JSON. Book pages have yet to conform but [they eventually will](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-83460?focusedCommentId=241836&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-241836).